# Исправление JS кода

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Подскажите, что не так с кодом, при клике на кнопку с классом **.menu-trigger** не к навигационному меню с классом **.navi** не добавляется класс **.ul-trigger**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-trigger').click(function() {
        $('.navi').addClass('ul-trigger')
    });
    $('.menu-trigger').click(function() {
    $('.navi').removeClass('ul-trigger')
    });

});
```

Comment: Ну, в данном коде написано добавить класс (в первом обработчике) и сразу же убрать его обратно (во втором обработчике), может оно так на самом деле и есть? :)

Comment: Дело в том, что это я раскомментировал, не работает код даже если просто оставить addClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А Вы случайно не забыли jquery подключить? Ниже примерно такой же код, но он работает.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-trigger').click(function() {
    if ($('.navi').hasClass('ul-trigger') == true) $('.navi').removeClass('ul-trigger');
    else $('.navi').addClass('ul-trigger');
  });
  //$('.menu-trigger').click(function() {$('.navi').removeClass('ul-trigger')});
});
```

```css
.ul-trigger {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="menu-trigger">menu</div>
  <div class="navi">navi</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, что-то протупил )

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('.menu-trigger').click(function(){
         $('.navi').toggleClass('ul-trigger');
    })
})
```